# Hook inside a Class in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, components, react-navigation

I would have liked to know how to navigate from screen to screen from the React Navigation module using the [useNavigation()](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/) function inside of a component. According to the documentation, you must include the useNavigation() function by including an onPress inside my tag (here ). The problem
is that it shows me the following error: 'Invariant violation: Invalid call. Hook can only be called inside of the body of a function component.'

My React Native Component :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity} from "react-native";
import { Text } from 'react-native-elements';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default class HorizontalCard extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        screen: PropTypes.string,
        title: PropTypes.string,
        desc: PropTypes.string,
        img: PropTypes.string,
      }
    render() {
        const navigation = useNavigation();
        return (
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate(this.props.screen)} style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.card_discord}>
                    <Image style={styles.card_discord_img} source={{uri: this.props.img}} />
                        <LinearGradient
                            start={[1.0, 0.5]}
                            end={[0.0, 0.5]}
                            colors={['rgba(42, 159, 255, 0.2)', '#333333', '#333333']}
                            style={styles.FadeAway}>
                            <View style={styles.FadeAway}>
                                <Text h4 style={styles.FadeAway_h2}>{this.props.title}</Text>
                                <Text style={styles.FadeAway_p}>{this.props.desc}</Text>
                            </View>
                        </LinearGradient>
                </View>   
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
}
```

Thanks.
Regards,

Quentin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot implement your components as `classes` if you want to use `hooks`.

So, if you want to use `hooks`, you should implement your components as `functions` since the **`hooks` can only be called inside the body of a `function component`.**

So, your component should be as follows.

**Implementing component as s FUNCTION and using HOOKS.**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Text } from 'react-native-elements';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

export function HorizontalCard(props) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate(props.screen)}
      style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.card_discord}>
        <Image style={styles.card_discord_img} source={{ uri: props.img }} />
        <LinearGradient
          start={[1.0, 0.5]}
          end={[0.0, 0.5]}
          colors={['rgba(42, 159, 255, 0.2)', '#333333', '#333333']}
          style={styles.FadeAway}>
          <View style={styles.FadeAway}>
            <Text h4 style={styles.FadeAway_h2}>
              {props.title}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.FadeAway_p}>{props.desc}</Text>
          </View>
        </LinearGradient>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

HorizontalCard.propTypes = {
  screen: PropTypes.string,
  title: PropTypes.string,
  desc: PropTypes.string,
  img: PropTypes.string,
};
```

But, if you still needs to implement your component as a `class`, you can forget about using `useNavigation` hook and continue with `this.props.navigation` instead.

In that case, your component should be as follows.

**Implement component as a CLASS and WITHOUT HOOKS**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Text } from 'react-native-elements';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class HorizontalCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  static propTypes = {
    screen: PropTypes.string,
    title: PropTypes.string,
    desc: PropTypes.string,
    img: PropTypes.string,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(this.props.screen)}
        style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.card_discord}>
          <Image
            style={styles.card_discord_img}
            source={{ uri: this.props.img }}
          />
          <LinearGradient
            start={[1.0, 0.5]}
            end={[0.0, 0.5]}
            colors={['rgba(42, 159, 255, 0.2)', '#333333', '#333333']}
            style={styles.FadeAway}>
            <View style={styles.FadeAway}>
              <Text h4 style={styles.FadeAway_h2}>
                {this.props.title}
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.FadeAway_p}>{this.props.desc}</Text>
            </View>
          </LinearGradient>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution actually I understand better now !

Comment: @SennenRandika just suggestion, the class based version can be used with a hook by wrapping inside a functional component, you can check out the docs here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan Yeah... I was not aware of that. I thought we must use function components if we want to use hooks. Thank you for commenting here and letting me know about that. :-)

Comment: You are welcome, We do that but for navigation the wrapping workaround can be used :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also wrap your class component in a function component to use the hook and get it though props:

```js
class MyBackButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // Get it from props
    const { navigation } = this.props;
  }
}

// Wrap and export
export default function(props) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return <MyBackButton {...props} navigation={navigation} />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use hooks inside Class components, as it clearly says in the error. Please check [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)